# How to put 'url' template tag into 'with'

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to cache return value of `{% url ..}` function to a variable with `with` template tag.

here is my code:
    {% with path=url "show_cart" %}
            
                 
            
    {% endwith %}

And with this code I get this exception: `TemplateSyntaxError` `u'with' received an invalid token: u'"show_cart"'`

Is it possible to assign result of `url` function to variable?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this. Not sure what Django version is required for this syntax:

```
{% url 'view' as the_url %}
{{ the_url }}
```

[Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) here